# Regex pattern to replace characters

Tags: regex, excel, vba, regexp-replace

The program contains text of this type:

> ```
> A B Ccccc
> A Ccccc
> ACcccc
> ABCcccc
> ```

I need only such text to remain:

> Ccccc

I wrote a replacement function, but I just can’t pick up a pattern
How to make such a pattern?

Comment: Do you need "CCccc" to remain, even if it es repeated inside the analyzed string?

Comment: Based on what logic the text to remain will be defined? If you do not know that, nobody will be able to help, I'm afraid...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I do not know the contents of the text, but I know that it will look like in the example. That’s why I thought I needed regular expressions

Comment: Please share more information. An screenshot would also help with the desired result. By the looks of it you don't need VBA nor Regex

Comment: @giovanii111; as far as I can understand your requirement; does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/BXaUIR/5) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex, nor VBA. It seems you simply are looking for the position of the last upper-case letter and then to extract from there:

[image]

Formula in `B1` (with Excel O365):

```
=MID(A1,MAX(SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))*(EXACT(UPPER(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))),LEN(A1))
```

If you don't have Excel O365:

```
=MID(A1,MAX(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))*(EXACT(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)),MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))),LEN(A1))
```

You probably need to enter as array through: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

If you must go through VBA and regex then a pattern [`like`](https://regex101.com/r/BXaUIR/7):

```
[A-Z][^A-Z]*$
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed `[A-Z][^A-Z]*$`